# Social Counters Causing Slow Load

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, twitter, google-plus

I am fitting my blog with some social counters on the home page. The blog shows 10 posts and loads more with infinite scroll.

Considering it has to do 3 requests per post, and also has to display 10 posts - that means 30 requests have to go through before the page is displayed.

Using get_transient / set_transient it seems to make the page load instantly but after every hour, 1 person will have bad load times - just wondering if I can make it faster by checking with jQuery if the variables have changed or not (if they have, then make it do requests after page load).

I don't know jQuery at all really, and would appreciate some help with this.

```
function getShares($url){
    $fbcount = get_transient('share_count');
    if ($fbcount !== false) return $fbcount;
    $fbcount = 0;

    $fql = "SELECT share_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = '".$url."'";
    $apifql = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode( $fql );
    $json = file_get_contents( $apifql );
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $fbcount = $data[0]->share_count;
    set_transient('share_count', $fbcount, 60*60);
    return $fbcount;
}

function getPlus1($url) {
    $gpcount = get_transient('plusone_count');
    if ($gpcount !== false) return $gpcount;
    $gpcount = 0;

    $html =  file_get_contents( "https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=".urlencode($url));
    $doc = new DOMDocument();   $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $counter=$doc->getElementById('aggregateCount');
    $gpcount = $counter->nodeValue;
    set_transient('plusone_count', $gpcount, 60*60);
    return $gpcount;
}

function getTweets($url){
    $tweetcount = get_transient('tweet_count');
    if ($tweetcount !== false) return $tweetcount;
    $tweetcount = 0;

    $json = file_get_contents( "http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=".$url );
    $ajsn = json_decode($json, true);
    $tweetcount = $ajsn['count'];
    set_transient('tweet_count', $tweetcount, 60*60);
    return $tweetcount;
}
```

Comment: better to use any lazy loading plugin..

Comment: I wanted to do it this way because I can customize the icons around the counts. With the other plugins I did not see any options for that.

Answer (score 0):

Store results to database and if results are older than an hour - redownload it again.

(And of course put it to database again with new data).

You don't even need jQuery for this.

Comment: I was under the impression that get/set transient used SQL to save its data. It caches fine for now, but I am just wondering for that one user every hour, if this can be sped up some.

Comment: It'll be fast, dont worry about speed